# mini-faq for proposals

Tags: feature-request, area-51, definition-phase

Many proposal-specific questions on the direction etc. arise from comments. Allowing the proposal site during definition phase to provide a mini-faq (only editable by followers or maybe even only the proposing person and those entitled by him/her) could help clarifying this, also letting new followers know what kind* of questions they should focus their votes on.

*) only what *kind* of, not *which* ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "faq" for a proposal is effectively the list of on and off topic questions.

That's a more useful, practical artifact than a lot of undirected discussion.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I intended this for definition phase so the example questions get shaped easier

Comment: One mans artifact is most other peoples junk...

Comment: So when will there be a discussion about borderline question @Jeff? I'd rather have this discussion before beta, so that we don't have to on a closing streak afterwards

Comment: @ivo remember that every single new beta site will **have a per site meta**. Discuss it there. See blog for info, look specifically at the URLs there in red: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/

Comment: @Jeff I understand we can discuss it when site (including meta and chat) launch, but isn't it better to prevent than to cure? If the community already decides on what should not be allowed, it makes beta all the more easy. And hopefully we don't have discussions afterwards like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy

Comment: @Jeff then what about offering that during definition already? e.g. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/ #### /meta/