# Meta (or something) during commitment-phase

Tags: feature-request, area-51, meta, commitment-phase

There really should be something the followers or at least committed ones should be able to do during commitment-phase until beta has begun. I know, we're supposed to recruit experts then, but there is absolutely no way of coordination for now.

Comment: dupe, searching...

Comment: @Juan [Allow users to vote on site essentials during the Commitment Phase of Area51](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54230/allow-users-to-vote-on-site-essentials-during-the-commitment-phase-of-area51) perhaps? But it's only related, I ask about ways to communicated with others who committed

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53776/please-add-comments-to-the-commitment-phase is closer, but still closer to related than duplicate.

Comment: related: [mini-faq for proposals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54440/mini-faq-for-proposals)

Comment: ok ok, perhaps not a dupe then

Comment: Yes, during the commitment phase it's very confusing because there seems to be little to do at the site.  There's no easy way to contact people with over 200 rep to commit to it - you can't add questions - I just visit it and poke around.  There has to be a better way.